# System design: Strategies for dealing with heavy writes to a DB

Tags: architecture, scalability, system-design

From a systems design/scalability perspective, what are some industry-standard strategies in dealing with a system that requires heavy writes to a particular table in a DB.

For simplicity sake, let's say the table is an inventory table for products, and has a column 'Product Name', and a column 'Count', and it simply increments by +1 each time a new Product is bought into the system. And there are millions of users buying different products every second and we have to keep track of the latest count of each product, but it does not have to be strictly realtime, maybe a 5 min lag is acceptable.

My options are:

1. Master slave replication, where master DB handles all writes, and slaves handles reads. But this doesn't address the write-heavy problem
2. Sharding the DB based on product name range, or its hashed value. But what if there's a specific product (eg Apple) that receives large number of updates in a short time, it'll still hit the same DB.
3. Batched updates? Use some kind of caching and write to table every X number of seconds with a cumulative counts of whatever we've received in those X seconds? Is that a valid option, and what caching mechanism do I use? And what if there's a crash between the last read and next write? How do I recover the lost count?
4. Any other obvious choices I forgot about?

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: are you constrained to a particular DB? Cassandra is known to have high-write throughput and is distributed by design for scalability/high-availability

Comment: I'm more interested in the techniques and principles that allow high write throughput, not so much on which framework or db.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I’d say a solution will be highly dependent of what exactly you need to do. A solution to write thousands of *records* per second might be very different from incrementing a *counter* in the example you provided. More so, there could be no `tables` at all to handle such load. `Consistency`/`availability` requirements are also missing in your question and depending on them the entire architecture may be very different.

Anyway, back to your specific simplistic case and your options

#### Option 1 (Master slave replication)

The problem you’ll face here is database `locking` - every increment would require a record lock to avoid race conditions and you’ll quickly get your processes writing to your db waiting in a queue and your system down. Even under a moderate load )

#### Option 2 (Sharding the DB)

Your assumption is correct, not much different from p.1

#### Option 3 (Batched updates)

Very close. A caching layer provided by a light-weight storage providing concurrent **atomic** incremens/decrements with **persistence** not to lose your data. We’ve used `redis` for a similar purpose although any other [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database) would do as well - there are literally dozens of such databases around.

> A key-value database, or key-value store, is a data storage paradigm
>   designed for storing, retrieving, and managing associative arrays, a
>   data structure more commonly known today as a dictionary or hash table

The solution would look as follows:

```
incoming requests → your backend server -> kv_storage (atomic increment(product_id))
```

And you'll have a "flushing" script running i.e. `*/5` that does the following (simplified):

1. for every `product_id` in **kv_storage** read its current `value`
2. update your db counter (`+= value`)
3. decrement the `value` in kv_storage

#### Further scaling

- if the script fails nothing bad would happen - the updates would arrive on next run
- if your backend boxes can't handle load - you can easily add more boxes
- if a single key-value db can't handle load - most of them support scaling over multiple boxes or a simple sharding strategy in your backend scripts would work fine
- if a single "flushing" script doesn't keep up with increments - you can scale them to multiple boxes and decide what key ranges are handled by each one

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Follow up:

This kv_storage, eg, Redis, needs a separate DB for persistence? So I'll have server->redis->db store? If so this:

incoming requests → your backend server -> kv_storage (atomic increment(product_id))

This does not actually write to any database, just updates the redis cache in memory, right? The persistence is done by the flushing script every 5 mins?

Comment: It already has. You can configure how reliable it must be - there're multiple options, see https://redis.io/topics/persistence Typically there's a trade-off between performance and reliability

Comment: Can I use redis with a different backend db store, such as a traditional MySQL?

Comment: You can't, it has its own file-based storage system and all of its operations are built around it. It's much simpler than that of mysql so it shouldn't be a concern

Answer (score 5):

You asked a typical [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) question. "CQRS" stands for Command Query Responsibility Segregation. It is what it sounds like - you are separating your writes (commands) from your reads (queries). This approach solves problems when you have different needs between the writes and reads - exactly your situation.

To achieve this in a scalable fashion, you need to *acknowledge* (i.e., *accept*) a request to increment, and queue it for processing. And let the reads work real-time per request. Process the queued requests with a *background* command handler which knows *how to reconcile*. i.e., if it fails, it should know how to resolve a conflict (e.g., if somebody else updated the row, retrieve a newer version and try again).

I completely disagree with another answer where somebody suggested that queuing will bring down your entire system. Queueing does not bring anything down, because it's queuing and not real-time processing. That's the point of scaling. It's the opposite - making a change real-time, even if this means just to change a boolean flag in an in-memory cache, is much worse than queuing. Just think what will happen if the in-memory cache is down at that exact moment. Asynchronous offline (background) processing ensures that such problems don't prevent the command to be eventually processed.
However, you may need to either process the queued commands slowly (whatever pace it can handle without affecting reads) or in a separate copy of the data.

You could use a specific technology like in-memory cache as others suggested, but that again is yet another implementation of CQRS paradigm. It could be a cache or just another copy of the record or a database. Same thing and same effect.

Comment: 1. It was said that updating the same record from multiple processes in parallel  would make the processes wait for each other => on a moderate load the system would collapse, not that "queuing will bring down your entire system". 2. Whatever queueing system you'd use you'll need to make a decision on what matters most - durability or speed because still you'll need to save the items somewhere and it's not always possible and reasonable to flush every request to a disk immediately rather than accumulating them in memory for a while so there's always a chance to lose some data

Comment: 3. I'm not suggesting an 'in-memory cache' only - please read again 4. Is it correct that in a particular case suggested by the author you'd use an intermediate queue and create a new message for every increment request?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your answer. Yes, you understood my answer correctly. To have the highest reliability of processing every increment request, you need a queue.

Comment: In your answer, you suggested that every request updates the in-memory cache. That's not reliable and will be slower than queuing a command.
Also, I hope you noticed that the question clarified availability vs. consistency. The 5-minute delay means eventual consistency is acceptable. I don't recommend to do anything per every request if the number of commands is much higher than the number of queries.
Anyway, This at least clarifies the differences between your suggestion and mine.